# C# WPF Change Datagrid Cellcolor after property value has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I already tested different proposed solutions from here, but nothing worked for me.

So... I have a `ObservableCollection` which contains a list of an object that extends the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The objects in the `ObservableCollection` are changed perennially. The GUI works fine and the `DataGrid` shows the changes and updates in the different rows and cells. But now i want to change the color of the cell for about 5 seconds where the value of the object has changed. Does anybody know how do make this possible in XAML?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_future" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="378,10,-407,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Height="444" 
          Width="602">
</DataGrid>
```

This is my XAML code. I assigned the `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource` and then first the objects are added to the `ObservableCollection` and later the objects in the `ObservableCollection` are updated if there are changes. The columns are autogenerated in the `DataGrid`.

Now i tried something like that:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_test" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"  
           AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
           Margin="378,10,-407,0"  
           VerticalAlignment="Top"  
           Height="444"  
           Width="602">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" 
                                Binding="{Binding ID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" 
                                Binding="{Binding Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

The ID will not be updated. But how do i highlight the changes for 5 seconds?

Comment: Can you post the code here as well?

Comment: @serge1peshcoff i added my XAML code..

Comment: We need to see the cell template that you are currently using. If you want you can subscribe to the `TextBlock` or `TextBox` Binding updated event and then manipulate the background of that element to highlight the change.

Comment: @XAMlMAX right now i am not using any cell template. The columns are autogenerated in the datagrid.

Comment: You need to create those templates and then update source trigger set ot explicit. Then you will have the ability to highlight the changes.

Comment: @XAMlMAX updated my XAML

Comment: You could set a timer to run anytime the specified property is changed. The timer would change a property in the model. Then the datagrid trigger could change based on that property.